# In QML when populating a Combobox model how can I use a csv list?

Tags: qt, combobox, model, qml

I am trying to build dynamic combo boxes in QML using a csv list.  I am converting the list to an array and it looks like it should work, but no such luck.  If I manually insert the array using the exact same format it does indeed work.  What am I missing?

I can get it to work by simply copying and pasting the output of the console.log(model) but not when using it directly.

First I convert the csv to an array in my component build function

```
    var combo_list =[];
    // get csv count and then convert list to an array
    Default_Value.split(",").forEach( (x,y) => combo_list.push(x));       
    // now I add it to my options and return it to my QML component
    var options = {
        "options_ComboList":Qt.binding(function() {return String(JSON.stringify(combo_list))})};

    question_options_Object = component_options_object.createObject(mainCol,options);
```

Within my QML component

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Dialogs.qml 1.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import "."

Item {
    id: options_entry_item
    height: 140

    //inputs to question
    property var options_ComboList  //array lands here

            ComboBox {
                id: comboBox
                //model: JSON.stringify(options_ComboList)  // does not work, adds slashes around commas
                //model: options_ComboList // does not work, but outputs a correct array format when sent to console
                model: ["0:Use DipSwitch Settings","1:Safe/AGM-1 Bulk 14.1v","2:FLA 1(Starter) Bulk 14.8"]  // when copied/pasted from console.log of model: options_ComboList it works perfectly

            }

            Component.onCompleted: {
                console.log("Combobox model: "+comboBox.model);
           // output is: Combobox model: ["0:Use DipSwitch Settings","1:Safe/AGM-1 Bulk 14.1v","2:FLA 1(Starter) Bulk 14.8"]

            }
        }
```

No errors are emitted

Answer (score 2):

After a bit more research I found the problem.  All I needed to do was to parse the array going into my model  So my input to my model becomes.

```
ComboBox {
    id: comboBox
    model: JSON.parse(options_ComboList)
}
```

Hope this helps others!